# Is there such a bip32 function?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, bitcoinjs, bip44

I have this code:

```
const bip32 = utils.BIP32Factory(utils.ecc)
const mnemonic = utils.bip39.generateMnemonic(256);
const seed = utils.bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);
const masterNode = bip32.fromSeed(seed);
const masterNode= bip32.fromPrivateKey(Buffer.from(masterPrivateKey, 'hex'));  //HERE
```

is there a way to derive the entire masternode from its private key? The reason why I want to do this is because for each user belonging to my platform I want to associate the private key of the masterNode to be able to then derive all the wallets (managed with BIP44) that he owns and that he has generated.